# Is deploying that expensive?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, golang

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract and get this error each time

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [contract creation code storage out of gas]

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
// it has trouble with workspace
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Royalty.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract BaseCollection is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Royalty, Ownable, Pausable, AccessControl {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol
    ) ERC721(name, symbol) {
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(PAUSER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    function pause() public onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyRole(PAUSER_ROLE) {
        _unpause();
    }

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Royalty) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, AccessControl, ERC721Royalty)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

Then I generated abi and bin with

```
solc --optimize --abi ./contracts/contract.sol -o ./abi/collection --overwrite
solc --optimize --bin ./contracts/contract.sol -o ./bin
```

I generate my Go library with

```
abigen --bin=./smart-contracts/bin/BaseCollection.bin --abi=./smart-contracts/abi/collection/BaseCollection.abi --pkg=contract_collection --out=./core/repositories/contracts/collection/collection.go --type Collection
```

I try to deploy it this way

```
    auth, err := bind.NewKeyedTransactorWithChainID(privateKey, big.NewInt(5))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    auth.Nonce = big.NewInt(int64(nonce))
    auth.Value = big.NewInt(0)      // in wei
    auth.GasLimit = uint64(1000000) // in units
    auth.GasPrice = gasPrice
    address, tx, instance, err := contract_collection.DeployCollection(auth, client, "test", "yes")
```

But each time I run this function I get this error, here is the etherscan of my wallet
https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7a7da62d3e43beb63c30a341362039cddf71babd

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried at quiet hours and it worked, I've seen on Reddit that there was unusual gas fees for goerli and that's the reason people had trouble deploy.

[image: goerli gas fees chart from 19/10/22 to 26/10/22]

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with the triggering of `Create` in the EVM code. You can increase your gas limit above 1000000 and try again.

See:

[contract creation code storage out of gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19725/contract-creation-code-storage-out-of-gas)

[How to fix: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87475/how-to-fix-warning-error-encountered-during-contract-execution-out-of-gas)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried it doesn't work unfortunately